# Elements misposition at resize (using max-width:100% to scale rel. to window size)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` on all my `<img>` elements and on my `image slider wrapper`.

When resizing the browser window, the images scale correctly, but many surrounding elements don't follow along and misposition. They will self-correct once the page is refreshed or next image is loaded in the image slider. Any ideas?

[Demo](http://www.nobodyfilm.org) - scale the window, css at line 25

Answer (score 0):

Pikachoose library sets the sizes of a few elements on each animation.

```
<div class="pika-stage" style="height: 355px;">

<div class="pika-aniwrap" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 835px;">
```

This is why everything fixes itself when the next animation happens. You could look though the source and replicate the animations re-sizing code and put it in a $(window).resize event handler. Looking at the docs for Pikachoose it seems that they have a goto method.

You could do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){$('#pikame').data('pikachoose').GoTo(3)})
```

Where the index of 3 is the current active slide. You probably want to use a form of timeout and only call it once to improve performance.

```
var resizeSlider = null

$(window).resize(function(){
  if(resizeSlider) clearTimeout(resizeSlider)
  resizeSlider = setTimeout(function() {
     $('#pikame').data('pikachoose').GoTo(3)
  }, 300)
})
```

This should make it so the goto is fired 300ms after the last window.resize event.

Hope this gives you some ideas.